# add_timer inside kernel timer function doesn't require scheduling?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

When we use kernel timers, kernel timers are run in software interrupt, so kernel timer function runs in timer interrupt context.

```c
void timer_func(unsigned long arg)
{
    my_timer.expires = jiffies + HZ;
    add_timer(&my_timer);
}
```

So `add_timer()` inside kernel timer function does not need scheduling?
Because in interrupt context scheduling is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `add_timer` function can be used in interrup context. Calling it within timer callback function is a standard way for repeatedly doing something.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP means "how come it works in interrupt ctx?". 
So, add_timer() itself does not invoke schedule() directly; it calls mod_timer():

```
void add_timer(struct timer_list *timer)
{
    BUG_ON(timer_pending(timer));
    mod_timer(timer, timer->expires);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(add_timer);
```

and as the code comment above this functions clearly says:

```
"...
 * The kernel will do a ->function(->data) callback from the
 * timer interrupt at the ->expires point in the future. The
 * current time is 'jiffies'.
..."
```

So it does not directly invoke schedule(); it will invoke your timer function upon expiry. Note that the timer functionality runs in (soft) interrupt context, so don't do anything that will invoke schedule() directly or indirectly.